# Gdal Installation error using pip

Tags: python, pip, gdal

Im trying to install GDAL latest version using pip, but im getting the following error, Failed building wheel for GDAL.
My python version is 2.7.9, Please help me. It is installing gdal 1.11.3 version if i specify the version but i need latest version or >=2.0

Comment: maybe https://gist.github.com/cspanring/5680334 will help

Comment: Ya, I tried it gives as follow                                                    gdal_wrap.cpp
    C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python
\9.0\VC\Include\xlocale(342) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but un
wind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp(3085) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file
: 'cpl_port.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsof
t\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Comment: yea probably does not work on windows... try https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/installing-gdal-with-python-on-windows

Comment: Did you try to follow those instructions: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL ?

Comment: ya i followed and error as  C:\GDAL-2.1.3\GDAL-2.1.3\extensions\gdal_wrap.cpp(3085) : fatal error C1083: Can
not open include file: 'cpl_port.h': No such file or directory
error: command  'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\V
isual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Comment: Same error here VS2015/PythonTools missing cpl_port.h.
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I [a million include directories!!!] /EHsc /Tpextensions/gdal_wrap.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\extensions/gdal_wrap.obj
    gdal_wrap.cpp
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp(3168): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cpl_port.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Finally its worked with the command pip install C:\Users\admin\Downloads\GDAL-2.1.3-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl.

I downloaded GDAL-2.1.3-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl. from here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal

Comment: Still doesn't explain why gdal is missing required bits to build. How the heck did the famous "Golkhe" build it? But this is the way to get going, with Gohlke's WHL build

Comment: In my case, with Python version 3.6, this worked as well (of course with a different wheel file).

Comment: Worked with 3.7 a well.

Comment: @Reinier could you specify the wheel file? or where to get it?

Comment: @norman123123: Oh, it is from the same URL. It has wheel files for several different Python versions and for Win32 as well as Win64. Just choose the one you need.