# installing Gdal on Windows 10 with python 3.6.4: fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cpl_port.h'

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, windows-10, gdal

So I am trying to pip install gdal but got an error.

```
  extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp(3168): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cpl_port.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.13.26128\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

So I am running the following:

- Python 3.6.4 anaconda distribution
- Windows 10 (x64)
- Microsoft Visual 2017 Redistribute both x64 and x86 (both installed by the vs builder tool)

MS Visual was installed because of this error before

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
```

Here is the trace log for the error:

```
 C:\Users\0\Desktop\>pip install gdal
Collecting gdal
  Using cached GDAL-2.2.4.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: gdal
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for gdal ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\0\envs\ecoscan\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\0\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-wc3za_f8\\gdal\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\0\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp9t7nk1ompip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
  copying gdal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
  copying ogr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
  copying osr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
  copying gdalconst.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
  copying gnm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\osgeo
  copying osgeo\gdal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\osgeo
  copying osgeo\gdalconst.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\osgeo
  copying osgeo\gdalnumeric.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\osgeo
  copying osgeo\gdal_array.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\osgeo
  copying osgeo\gnm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\osgeo
  copying osgeo\ogr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\osgeo
  copying osgeo\osr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\osgeo
  copying osgeo\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\osgeo
  Fixing build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\gdal.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ogr.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\osr.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\gdalconst.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\gnm.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\osgeo\gdal.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\osgeo\gdalconst.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\osgeo\gdalnumeric.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\osgeo\gdal_array.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\osgeo\gnm.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\osgeo\ogr.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\osgeo\osr.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\osgeo\__init__.py
  Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
  Fixing build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\gdal.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\ogr.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\osr.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\gdalconst.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\gnm.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\osgeo\gdal.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\osgeo\gdalconst.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\osgeo\gdalnumeric.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\osgeo\gdal_array.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\osgeo\gnm.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\osgeo\ogr.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\osgeo\osr.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\osgeo\__init__.py
  Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
  running build_ext
  building 'osgeo._gdal' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\extensions
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -I../../ogr/ogrsf_frmts -I../../gnm -I../../apps -Ic:\users\0\anaconda3\include -Ic:\users\0\anaconda3\include -I. "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpextensions/gdal_wrap.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\extensions/gdal_wrap.obj
  gdal_wrap.cpp
  extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp(3168): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cpl_port.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.13.26128\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Any ideas how to fix this? I just want use the `ogr2ogr` in gdal to convert .shp to GeoJSON then to topojson.

Comment: Since you are using Anaconda, try to install gdal from conda instead of thorugh pip.
`conda install -c conda-forge gdal`

Comment: @the_cheff I actually just want to add it to the virtualenv I am using so I want to avoid conda. If there is no fix I think I will just download the binary and use the command line to execute functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and found the solution here:
[gdal-installation-error-using-pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43587960/gdal-installation-error-using-pip)

That is: download the wheel file and install from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer use conda instead, I was stuck at the same issue for hours, this is the only solution to install GDAL I found.

> conda install gdal

Answer (score 0):

Install via wheels.

1. Download wheels suitable for you from here - [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal)
2. Format of wheel names e.g. **GDAL-3.4.3-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl**.
3. Explanation: *GDAL-VERSION-PYTHON_VERSION-PYTHON_VERSION-OS-ARCHITECTURE*.
4. Install with `python -m pip install GDAL-3.4.3-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl`